# How to stop a range of cells from recalculating in excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have about 11 million cells with various different formulas (vlookup, concatenate etc) in it, the calculation takes about half an hour on my laptop. I've set the calculation to update when I save the file.

The 11 million calculations are done, I don't need to do them again, I'd like to "freeze" them so the sheet doesn't calculate again. (when I click save it says "calculating: (#processor(s)): ##%" I don't want to copy and paste (as values) as I'd want to come back to the sheet later with a different set of inputs to make other calculations.

Is there a way to stop the already calculated cells to not calculate again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1025534/how-to-set-specific-cells-to-not-calculate-in-excel

Comment: strange that question didn't show up in the search, nor in the suggestions when I was typing out the question ...

Comment: also that has macros - which I am not using ... unless that is the answer.